# google maps API | JSON error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I keep getting a very weird error anytime I try to load coordinates to my project using markercluster. Anytime I add the `google.maps.LatLng` to the lat and lng I pull from the JSON file it converts it into the below error. For now all I'm trying to do is log the coordinates to the console. I've never seen this, hope someone can help me with it.

*This is what is loaded instead pf my JSON file:*

```
_.Ge {__gm: {…}, gm_accessors_: {…}, position: _.F, gm_bindings_: {…}, clickable: true, …}
```

Here is my code

```
function initMap(){
  var usa =   new google.maps.LatLng(37.090240, -95.712891);
  var mapZoom = 4;
  var markers = [];
  var stateLat = [];
  var stateCoord = [];
  console.log(stateCoord);

  markStates(stateCoord);

  var options = {
    'zoom': mapZoom,
    'center': usa,
    'styles': styles
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
  //var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers);
  //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': markers});
  // var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, stateCoord);

}

function markStates(sets){
  var coordLink = 'http://xxxxxx/xxx-xxxxxx/_json/states-coord.json';

  $.ajax({
    url: coordLink,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .done(function() {
    //console.log("success states loaded");
    $.getJSON(coordLink, function(data){
      $.each(data.usa, function(index, el) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(el.coordinates.lat, el.coordinates.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng});
        //var latLng = [lat, lng];
        sets.push(marker);

      });
    });

  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("error on states");
  });
}
```

JSON File sample:

```
{

    "usa": [{
            "state": "Alabama",
            "stateInit": "AL",
            "coordinates": {
                "lat": 32.806671, "lng": -86.791130
            }
        },
        {
            "state": "Alaska",
            "stateInit": "AK",
            "coordinates": {
                "lat": 61.370716, "lng": -152.404419
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `This is what is loaded` - why do you say that? did you `console.log(data)` before the `$.each(data.usa` ? the only console.log I see is for the marker, which would look like that

Comment: also, why are you using $.ajax for the url, then $.getJSON for the same url? two requests for the same data seems wrong

Comment: It's very hacky code. When I say loaded I mean what the console shows. Even if I do `console.log(latLng);` I get  _.F {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ} in the console.

Comment: yes, you would get that for latLng ... **your** data is in `data.usa` - what happens when you `console.log(data.usa)` or even `console.log(data)` ... you'll see **your** data ... wow

Comment: That is not what it's doing. It's not loading my data, I also want to load the lat and lng from the json file

Comment: console.log(data) ... what do you see ... your data ... anything else is objects created using your data, which wont look exactly like your data

Comment: I know that works. I want to store the lat and lng I pull from my JSON file I then want to store that data into my `latLng` variable so I could then add my markers to the map. logging data isnt gonna do that for me ... jesus

Comment: Exactly. Logging data does nothing. What is the problem. Your title says json error. What json error do you get.

Comment: Oh dear. Your json is invalid to begin with

Comment: Instead on the JSON data showing up in my console. This shows up
`_.F {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ}`
 as you can see that is not my data.

Comment: Where? Which console log produces that output

Comment: If you say it's the result of logging marker or latlng then you have not read a single comment

Comment: log under stateCoord variable 7 lines down

Comment: that is not your JSON data ... that is an array of google markers

Comment: what do you see if you `console.log(data)` **just above** `$.each(data.usa, function(index, el) {`

Comment: I get an object with my data, but I want to push this data into an array so I can then be able to add each marker to that location on the map. Hope I'm explaining this right.

Answer (score 0):

You're logging out the marker, which is an instance of google `Marker` object. That is not an error. If you want to get the coordinates, you need to ask for them specifically:

```
console.log(marker.getPosition())
```

That returns a `LatLng` object. Probably also not what you want. So you need to log that to something readable:

```
console.log(marker.getPosition().toString())
// alternatively
console.log(marker.getPosition().toJSON())
```

[Here's the full api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker) for the Marker object (and all of the objects actually.)

Comment: When I try to log that I get this in my console also `_.F {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ}`

Comment: yes, because it's a google object, nothing to do with your data in reality

Comment: Logging which? `marker.getPosition()` returns a `LatLng` object. If you want coordinates off that, you have to ask for them. That's why I showed 3 different log statements. The api docs are helpful.

Comment: 7th line down is a log for the stateCoord that I thought would contain the lat and lng in my JSON file, but instead I get other weird data like this `
_.Ge {__gm: {…}, gm_accessors_: {…}, position: _.F, gm_bindings_: {…}, clickable: true, …}`